# Complex agregation in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

For example I have a table in MS SQL Server:

```
Feature, Option1, Option2
-------------------------
Agent, Yes, No
Agent, No, No
Console, No, Yes,
Console, Yes, Yes
```

I need to write a query that returns:

```
Feature, Option1 Yes Count, Option2 Yes Count
---------------------------------
Agent, 1, 0
Console, 1, 2
```

What query should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select Feature,
       count(nullif(Option1,'no')) as 'Option1 Yes Count',
       count(nullif(Option2,'no')) as 'Option2 Yes Count'
from    table_name
group by feature
```